# Protect MultiIndex dtype while adding a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The `MultiIndex` has potential to be a useful and more flexible alternative to "panel" data. More flexible because, while a traditional panel has the same columns across panels, with hierarchical indexing you can group columns however you like. I cannot find a convenient way, however, to protect the date `dtype` in a MultiIndex, when not every column is associated with a date.

For example, start with a `DataFrame` having a date as part of each column's hierarchical label:

```py
import pandas as pd

letters = ["a", "b"]
dates = list(pd.date_range(start="2019-11-12", freq="D", periods=2))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([letters, dates], names=[None, "Date"])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=index)
df.loc[0, :] = 1
df.columns.get_level_values("Date").dtype
```

```py
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

With serious contorting, you can add a column that has no "Date" label.

```py
df2 = pd.concat((
    df,
    pd.DataFrame(
        data=["A"],
        columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["good"], [pd.np.nan]]),
    )),
    axis=1
)
df2.columns.get_level_values("Date").dtype
```

```py
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Not only has the `dtype` on "Date" been preserved, but inspecting `df2.columns` show's the "Date" level has not been lengthened.

There's got to be an easier way, like assignment to a new label:

```py
df3 = df.copy()
df3["bad"] = "A"
df3.columns.get_level_values("Date").dtype
```

```
dtype('O')
```

The "Date" level has lost its date type while gaining a new value equated to an empty string. An emtpy string! Doesn't work using `.loc` either. Suggestions?

---

Responding to comments:

```py
df2.columns
```

```py
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'good'], [2019-11-12 00:00:00, 2019-11-13 00:00:00]],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, -1]],
           names=[None, 'Date'])
```

There are two levels of "Date".

```py
df3.columns
```

```py
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'bad'], [2019-11-12 00:00:00, 2019-11-13 00:00:00, '']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=[None, 'Date'])
```

Starting from `df3 = df.copy()`, assigning to `df3["bad"]` adds to the levels of "Date". It becomes the original two with an empty string tacked on. Or with `df3[("bad", None)] = "A"` the added value is `NaT`.

Comment: is `df3[("bad", pd.np.nan)] = "A"` what you look for? I'm not sure I understand the question. or even `df3[("bad", None)] = "A"` seem to conserve the dtype

Comment: @Ben.T Yeah ... almost. Stupid me for not seeing that assignment with the tuple does protect the date dtype, but the resulting index is not identical to `d2.columns`. The second level has been lengthened to include `NaT`. The question is whether there is a more direct way to end up with the same columns as `d2`.

Comment: I think the "The second level has been lengthened to include NaT" is what I don't understand. when I print df2.columns and df3.columns I don't really see the difference, could you tell more where is the difference?

Comment: @Ben.T Elaborated. Thanks for your help!